# Does Google/YouTube allow downloads on embeded YouTube videos?

Tags: google-search-console, video, youtube, download

I have a music website where I embed music videos from YouTube. I plan to allow my website users to download these embeded videos using third party plugin for free. Does Google permit this or if I do so my domain will get banned from ever embedding their videos again or get banned from their Google search engine? I currently do not have AdSense on my site and I don't wish to put it.

Comment: Have you read through their teams and conditions? no your not allowed to  download peoples videos, as you do not have permission and there service does not allow it. Always check terms and conditions.

Comment: This is a type of piracy. It is illegal and should not be implemented at all. Be legal and just use AdSense if you want to monetize.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking to conduct illegal acts through 3rd party tools and even though an answer is posted, I feel such legal matters with youtube videos are better taken up with youtube directly than via guests here.

Answer (score 2):

Checking their [Terms](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms) it is clear that YouTube do not allow downloads with this line, section 4 A:

> You agree not to distribute in any medium any part of the Service or the Content without YouTube's prior written authorization, unless YouTube makes available the means for such distribution through functionality offered by the Service (such as the Embeddable Player).

However it is important to note that a company's T&C's are not law and there are situations where you are perfectly within your rights to do something not authorized in the Terms. For example, YouTube itself allows content creators to [choose a Creative Commons license](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797468?hl=en) for their videos and so if a band released a video with this license, you could legally copy and redistribute it (usually with attribution required - read the fine print).

There are also [fair use exceptions to copyright](http://copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html) which permit unlicensed use of copyright-protected works in certain circumstances. Because you mention that you run a music website I'm guessing you would not be covered by those exceptions but the bottom line is that you are risking heavy fines if your activity falls outside the law. That should be your main concern, not whether YouTube wants to allow it or not.

One last point - definitely check out [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) and its community of users if you have any more technical questions about how to download videos.